# Pasted text into Tinymce not getting posted into table

Tags: php, html, tinymce

When I paste some text into the Tinymce editor using ctrl+v and then I click on the submit button, the text doesn't get inserted into the database. The page loads but nothing gets posted. If I type the same thing, it gets posted,but doesn't work when I paste it. What could be the issue? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of let us know that what plugins you have been activated using tinymce because i have implmented tinymce in my project and i can copy anything from anywhere and directly paste it in anything and it will save into database. make sure that in plugins u have activated paste functionality.

```
 plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime  nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality emoticons **paste** textcolor responsivefilemanager"
   ],
```

hope this will help you.

Regards

Imran Qasim